# Azure permission : not authorized to perform this operation

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

So i have a data factory which calls an Azure-function which reads blob storage.

I don't understand why i am getting this error.
"This request is not authorized to perform this operation". Is it a problem with data factory, azure storage, or azure function?

I have also added service principals to Storage Blob Data Contributor, without any success.

What permission should i add in storage explorer on this specific folder ? [image]

```json
{
    "name": "TPFunction",
    "instanceId": "4ef6513ebfc6bb",
    "runtimeStatus": "Failed",
    "input": {
        "environment": "dev",
        "DateToProcess": "2013-04-08",
        "SourceStorageType": "AdlsGen2",
        "SourceAccountName": "storage06",
        "SourceBlobContainer": "data",
        "SourceFilePath": "file/file/file"
    },
    "customStatus": null,
    "output": "Orchestratorfunction 'TPFunction' failed: Following error occurred during execution: The activity function 'TPFunction' failed: \"Error occurred getting list of files: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.\nRequestId:7b5e-e4a603\nTime:2013-04-08:02:27.0924606Z\r\nStatus: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.)\r\nErrorCode: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch\r\n\r\nHeaders:\r\nServer: Windows-Azure-HDFS/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0\r\nx-ms-error-code: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch\r\nx-ms-request-id: 7b5e-e4a603\r\nx-ms-version: 2019-07-07\r\nx-ms-client-request-id: e7357b5e-e4a603cc52\r\r\nContent-Length: 227\r\nContent-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n\". See the function execution logs for additional details.",
    "createdTime": "2021-01-04T19:02:24Z",
    "lastUpdatedTime": "2021-01-04T19:02:27Z"
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your function?

Comment: unfortunately i can't but the problem has been solved. One of the service principals was missing as Storage Blob Data Contributor.

Comment: If you don't have more problem, can we end this question now?:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I post here the major situation of '403 forbidden', and also post related methods to solve this.

**First situation,** we didn't give the access permission to the function app.

**`Solution:`**

If you want to access the storage blob data, you need to give related service the 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' RBAC role.

**Second situation,** storage has been protected by firewall.

**`Solution:`**

1, First way, add the outbound IP of the web app to the whitelist of storage.

2, Second way, create a virtual network on azure.

[image]

[image]

Then add the network to the firewall setting of storage:

[image]

Comment: I am also facing the 403 error when azure api accessing the blob storage, Please check this post                                                          
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76370426/this-request-is-not-authorized-to-perform-this-operation-azure-blob

Comment: Note using `Storage Blob Data Contributor` and not `Storage Account Contributor` (which does not give access to data).