# StorageError: This request is not authorized to perform this operation

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

I have deployed a nodejs program intp an azure webapp, this program expose an api to save blobs into azure storage account.
the program work fine on localhost, but when I deploy the program on the azure web app it gives this error :

```
StorageError: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
```

is it a network problem, should I add the ip address of the webaap into the storage account network ?

thanks for you help

Comment: _"should I add the ip address of the webaap into the storage account network?"_ - Yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure permission: Not authorized to perform this operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65604223/979052)